# How do I open an anaconda prompt

Tags: ubuntu, anaconda

I have installed Anaconda on my Ubuntu 16.04 operating system. The instructions I was following seemed to think I would have a desktop icon, but I don't. I eventually found out that I needed to type anaconda-navigator in my terminal to open it.

I am now trying to open an anaconda prompt. The lack of search results on how to do so, leads me to believe that it's very trivial under normal circumstances. But I don't see any icon, and when I look for anaconda or prompt in my apps, Ubuntu returns nothing.

I have also tried typing anaconda-prompt in the terminal, but no joy.

Is there something wrong with my installation or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Have you tried `conda`

Comment: No. Conda is part of Anaconda right?

Comment: Anaconda Prompt is only a "thing" on Windows. On Linux and macOS, you use the normal terminal emulator application, which should already be set for using conda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [darthbith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2449192/darthbith) said above: "Anaconda Prompt is only a "thing" on Windows"